# loadview VS interface builder

Tags: ios

Since I've seen many other IOS projects written in obj-C, I found that many of them do not use interface builder or storyboard file. It's hard to see what's going on. And I've known that loadview method should do the things similarly to drag and drop objects in IB. So what is the difference between loadview method and doing some dragging objects in interface builder?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you don't have AutoLayout (unless you use hard code to constraints too) and Size Classes without interface builder.

Working with IB is much less coding and more clarity.

If you add a Label to IB then the IB is responsible to release that object. And it's added to the view of course so you don't have to.

I would never go without IB now and would recommend to do so for other devs.

I use Size Classes + AutoLayout and all my screens looks good on every device plus that iOS9 is coming out: I have multiple screens auto enabled because I used Size Classes. **App works without maintenance for many years..**

Answer (score 0):

Simple difference between IB and loadView

IB:
All u can do is drag and drop things without having any code written.

loadView:
It is first viewCycle method which calls on loading any view of corresponding viewcotroller, You should do all your stuff programmatically here. like adding subviews to your view. and adding constraints etc.

Thanks